# Javascript variable, increment function?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the following JavaScript code:

```
$( "#toggleLog-1" ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggled-1" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
$( "#toggleLog-2" ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggled-2" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
$( "#toggleLog-3" ).click(function() {
  $( "#toggled-3" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
/// ... and many other IDs
```

As you can see, I want to know how to increment the id and compact my code, because I have many IDs in my css file. In php I know how I would do this (with a foreach and increment function), but how can I do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, how about:

```
$("[id^=toggleLog]").click(function() {
    var idNum = this.id.split("-")[1];
    $("#toggled-" + idNum).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Clean solution :) +1

Answer (score 4):

Although all your clickable elements seem to conform to a specific convention with their `id` attributes, it would be easier and cleaner to give all the clickable elements a specific class, and a `data-*` attribute specifying a selector for what element to toggle. For example, have this structure:

```
<div class="toggler" data-toggler="#toggled-2"></div>
<div id="toggled-2"></div>
```

And use this:

```
$(".toggler").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        toggler = $this.attr("data-toggler");

    $(toggler).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

It targets all the clickable elements by the `toggler` class. In the click handler, it looks at its specific `data-toggler` attribute, and selects elements by that, calling `.slideToggle()` on any found.